# Spilled coffee on laptop and matress

Tags: cleaning, house-cleaning, stain, laptop, liquids

Spilled coffee upon laptop & bed-sheet which has been absorbed into mattress too. Not only the bed-sheet but the mattress too has been stain due to spillage & seepage. Coffee is all over laptop keyboard too.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

**First, unplug the laptop and remove the battery** (or, it it's not removable, open the case and disconnect *one* wire from the battery). Also remove the clock battery. This prevents damage due to short-circuit and electrolytic corrosion.

Now, take the time to wash the spill from the laptop with *distilled water*. Remove the HDD and loudspeaker, if possible, but all other components can probably survive a dip in distilled water, though avoid water inside the display. After a water wash, wash with 90% or stronger alcohol (isopropyl or ethyl) *a few times* to remove the water.

Let the laptop air-dry **thoroughly** before reinstalling either battery and the power supply.

As for the mattress, blot with towels repeatedly, first wet and then dry. Any lingering smell of coffee should make it easier to get up in the morning.